# In nodejs/sqlite3, run's first callback parameter return the class instance, how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sqlite, electron

I've got the following class in TypeScript:

```
class Log
{
    public id: number;
    public text: string;

    construct(text: string){
        this.text = text;
    }

    save(){
        db.run(
            `insert into logs(text) values (?) `,
            this.text,
            ((this: RunResult, err: Error | null) => {
                if(err){
                    //...
                }
                console.log(this);//expecting RunResult{} but Log{}
            })
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to update the id of log instance by using `RunResult.lastID` in callback func block, and `@types/sqlite3/index.d.ts` includes this declaration:

```
    run(params: any, callback?: (this: RunResult, err: Error | null) => void): this;
```

However, `this` in callback parameters is type of Log rather than type of RunResult.

How can i get the correct RunResult instance? `this.lastID` expecting a value rather than `undefined`

Comment: Using `this` as in-parameter name is probably not wize, try change it to `result` or something and see if it's the RunResult rather than Log instance you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword in the `run` function parameters is not an argument to be passed, but it's the function context. Additionally, the arrow function does not have a context, so it's true that the `this` keyword inside your callback refers to the `Log` class.

So, first, you have to preserve the `Log` class context outside your callback and use a normal function as a callback instead of the arrow function.

Here is the revised `save` function:

```
save() {
    const instance = this;
    db.run(
        `insert into lorem(info) values (?) `,
        this.text,
        function (err: Error | null) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        instance.id = this.lastID;
        console.log(this);
        }
    );
}
```